# Can I change the wrapper element for apos-area and its widgets?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

By default an `apos.area` wraps its widgets in a `<div>`, plus each widget itself is wrapped in a `<div>`. Like below:

```
<div class="apos-area">
    <div class="apos-area-widget-wrapper" data-apos-widget-wrapper="page-link">
        <div class="apos-area-widget"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="apos-area-widget-wrapper" data-apos-widget-wrapper="page-link">
        <div class="apos-area-widget"><a href="/new-page">New Page</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have semantic markup and make the area wrapper a `<ul>` and the widget-wrappers `<li>` tags for specific areas, like the above navigation example. I couldn't find an option to pass to the widgets or the wrapper to make this happen - is there one, or is there another way to make this happen?

Comment: Did that answer work out? Feel free to join us in the Apostrophe Discord if you have other questions. https://chat.apostrophecms.org

Comment: I haven't had a chance to come back to this yet (it's for a side project), but I'm hoping to this coming weekend. I'll give your first answer a go and let you know how it goes. Thanks for providing so much info!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few answers to this.

### answer one (how we do it):

I'll get to answering the specific question, but firstly I wouldn't recommend doing something like a nav this way. If you want to let editors build the nav manually rather than use the page tree (not unusual), try creating a navigation widget or the use the `apostrophe-global` module and set the nav items as an array of links. Then you can create a nice, clean template or macro with the right markup. That's how we approach this in the Apos core team.

The Open Museum project has [an example of a nav macro](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/blob/4cf8638df1c0f50883c34a6bffeaf250dad57750/views/navigation.html), though it does use the page tree. You'd be passing in `data.global.navLinks` or whatnot instead of using the built-in page tree.

### answer two (the simple, unhelpful one):

No, there's no built-in way to do this. Widgets are generally thought of as fairly self-contained components. One more reason is that using widgets for small things like individual nav items would be difficult because the UI could get cramped and difficult to use.

### answer three (hack it):

Fortunately it's pretty easy to override core templates, so you could do this in your project.

⚠️ Again, don't go this way, but it's a useful example of overriding templates. ⚠️

In your project you could override the area template by copying the core `lib/modules/apotrophe-areas/views/area.html` file and putting it in your project in the same place. Then edit as you please. For the area wrapper, you could:

```html
{% set areaEl = data.options.areaEl or 'div' %}
<{{areaEl}} class="apos-area{% if data.options.blockLevelControls %} ... >
  /* ... area stuffing */
</{{areaEl}}>
```

Then in your page/widget template, put `areaEl: 'ul'` in your area options and it'll replace the div.

Once more for the folks in the back, **don't do this in your project**. When you find yourself overriding something this core, there's probably an easier way (answer one).